# Almost done...one problem with an error JPaneOption box

Tags: java

I've almost got my asignment done.   Yayy!  But.... I have two problems in my handler.  For one, I have a public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) method that is supposed to print a registrants name to a text field, plus the type of registration he is (student, business, complimentary).   I have this working, only it prints twice to the text area.  I don't get that.  Also, there is a  'calculate charges' button which is used to...well, calculate the charges.  When the button is clicked, the action event is supposed to check to make sure that a combo box (in a class called regPanel) does not have "Please select a registration type" which is element 0 in an object array.  The way I have it now, if I don't pick something from the combobox (leaving it on element 0), I get the error message, but then the program prints to the textfield anyways.  It is not supposed to.  It is only supposed to print the error box, then allow the user to make the proper selections.  Any advice would be appreciated. Here is the class:

```
public class ConferenceHandler implements ActionListener, FocusListener, ItemListener
{
    protected final static String ERROR_TEXT = "Please enter a name";
    protected ConferenceGUI gui;  //reference the ConferenceGUI panel
    /**Constructor*/
    public ConferenceHandler(ConferenceGUI gui) {this.gui = gui;}     


            if (gui.regPanel.getRegType() == "Please select a type")
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a registration type",
                    "Type Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //prints to textarea if registrant will be attending keynote or not
            else if (gui.regPanel.regCheckBox.isSelected())
                gui.textArea.append("\nKeynote address will be attended");
            else
```

Did a little more googling, and figured out the problem with the double firing of the itemStateChanged affair.  Trimmed all of the extra code out, because I'm pretty sure that all I need is a loop of some sort around here.  When I put  a while or do-while loop, all that happens is the JOptionPane comes up and won't go away.  I need to validate that the user has entered an appropriate checkbox selection, though.

Comment: Before asking new questions, you should upvote and accept answers in your other questions, as has been recommended to you before.

Comment: I know.  I mentioned on the last one that I am having troubles getting registered.  I will figure it out, I would just like to have my homework done before I do that, and put my kids to bed, and, and, and.  I understand the great amount of help that everyone has been.  I am not a 19 year old kid (although I know you have no way of knowing that).  I am old enough to parent myself.  Thank you for your concern, I know I am not using the best etiquette, but I will soon rectify that.

Comment: I just tried again, and it will not allow me to create an open ID tag.  I do not have accounts with gmail, facebook, or any of the others mentioned.  I again followed the links to create a new account, and again it did not work.  If you were here with me (trying to get supper ready for the kids), I would feed you and probably even buy you a coffee.  We Canadians are a thankful lot.  I do appreciate all of your help, even if it isn't translating into 10 rep points at the moment.

Comment: There, I went and signed up with stupid yahoo. Even upvoted your wifely chastisement.......

Comment: Note that you don't need to register the account in order to be able to vote/accept posts. But having a registered account is always better :)

Comment: See, and I tried on a few occassions to vote up, but it told me I had to sign in or register.  No matter now.

Comment: wifely chastisement? LOL!  And no, I'm not looking for points for me, since I haven't answered any of your questions and in fact can't get any meaningful upvotes from you.  Rather it was for the deserving others.  Thanks for fixing this.

Comment: No sweat.  I'm just screwing with you.  I fixed it, by the way.  Just needed a bunch of properly nested if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this working, only it prints twice to the text area.

You still haven't posted a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem as you where asked in a previoius question.

Copying and pasting a few lines of code from your real problem does not help you isolate the problem.

As a beginner, you need to learn how to simplify problems. Once you simplify the problem it is easier to find and solve the problem.

In this case a working SSCCE will be about 20 lines of code. A couple lines to create the GUI, a few more to add the compnonents and a few more to create the ItemListener.

Post your SSCCE and I'll post the answer to your question. This is a common mistake when working with an ItemListener. I could probably give you the answer without seeing your SSCCE, but you need to learn how to create a SSCCE for when you encounter more complex problems. So this question is a good place to start.

Maybe looking at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an Item Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)will help you understand what is happening.

Comment: In no way do I mean to be a dink, but as I said after the code-part of my post, I managed to figure out the problem with the double firing.  About the SSCCE, I think you are giving me a valuable peice of advice, and when I'm not swimming in this much s**t from all of the homework, I will definitely look into a more effective way of presenting the problem.  I can certainly sense more than a note of frustration, and I guess seeing as you hae over 20000 rep pts, you have had your fill of helping out annoying new people.  In my previous career I had to help new people, I know how it can be.

Comment: Any ways, now the only problem I am having is that I can't get the loop to work properly.  I know it is just a simple problem, but I can't see it at this point.  I don't think there needs to be too much code, but some people say, "Post more code!"  And I really don't know where to draw the line.

Comment: I just gave you an example of where to draw the line The point is to ignore the program you are working on. Create something simply that demonstrate what you are trying to do. If it works great. If not, then you have simple code to post on the forum.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have thought in the past that I am doing that, but some guys will say I should post the whole program.  Guess I just need practice.

Comment: There.  I cut it down to (mainly) the five or six offending lines that I can't figure out how to loop around.  Thanks.

Comment: I would say about 75% of the time, when I am able to create a SSCCE that accurately illustrates the problem and go to paste it into a new question, I stop because the answer jumps out at me. Make no mistake: **computer science is 90% solving problems smartly and 10% coding it up**

Comment: I wish the answer would jump out at me.  I have been looking at how to validate this for far too long.....

Comment: @glowcoder, exactly. @unit, that is still NOT a SSCCE! Have you read the link? How do I compile and execute that code to see the problem you are attempting to describe? Don't use "==" to compare Strings. Use the equals(...) method. That is the last advice I have until a proper SSCCE is posted.

Comment: Gotcha.  I wasn't trying to make a SSCCEE.  I can tell that it is quite important to you.  I fixed the problem, too. Thanks.  Will read uup on the SSCCEE, don't want to see you stroke.